# Solr analyzer default type

Tags: solr, analyzer, fieldtype

For the definition below, what is the default type of the analyzer? Is the definition assumed for both query and index analyzers?

```
<fieldType name="text_nicesort" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the type is not defined, the same analyzer is used for both index and query.

Comment: @Carl: you can see it in the source code: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/fe0ffb1a22042774fd1597f42a1aff87de552659/solr/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/IndexSchema.java#L384